# C# GetFiles from local variable

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get a path from SQL, create a variable to store the path, and then use GetFiles to get all of the files in that directory.

I have verified that the path exists and, when I write the result, it shows up correctly.  However, I am getting an unknown exception every time it tries to access the directory.  Hopefully someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);

myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FolderSource FROM MonitoredFolders WHERE FolderSource IS NOT NULL", myConnection);

try
{
     string returnvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     Console.WriteLine(returnvalue);
     Console.ReadLine();

     string[] filepath = Directory.GetFiles("@" + "\"" + returnvalue + "\"", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}

catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}

myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: The exception you are getting would certainly help in debugging.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `returnvalue` holds a valid path?

Comment: Sorry the exception when running the exe from my server: Application: ConsoleApplication1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at ConsoleApplication1.Class1.Main()

Comment: Is your program running as a user without permissions to the folder?

Comment: I have run it from a server that I know has permission and from my desktop.  The returnvalue shows up as the correct UNC path so I assume it is holding the value.

Comment: what is the valid way to add quotes?  Every where I have seen says "\""

Comment: Did you try just - string[] filepath = Directory.GetFiles(  @"returnValue" , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: I just tried Console.WriteLine(filepath); and got this is a result System.String[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant dynamically construct a string with using @ token as part of the dynamic string and expect it to work with a literal. @ in literal is interpreted by compiler/runtime

`string a = @"abc";` is different from `string b = "@abc";`

In your example, you should not do "@" + "\"" + ...
As the returnvalue is already a string type, you don't need to surround them in quote again and definitely not the "@" too. If in doubt, debug and drag that expression to the watch window. You will see that you ended up with string that looks like "@\"xxxxx\""

Make sure the returnvalue has the correct path value. If in doubt, System.IO.Path class gives you a range of static methods that can help you test or manipulate path string.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I got rid of all of the extra stuff that I was passing through and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the application without accessing the database just by executing it with a path that you know works.

```
string directory = @"C:\temp"
 string[] filepath = Directory.GetFiles(  directory , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

It looks to me as if the first argument of GetFiles is not constructed correctly.

Comment: you are right Malcolm.  GetFiles is not liking any variable.  I am going to have to find something that will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to do two things in one line of code.  It makes debugging very difficult as you have found.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    String Dir = "Temp";

    String SearchDir = @"\" + Dir + @"\";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying with a UNC path, please add two back slashes ("\\") before your 'returnValue' variable.

Comment: This is what I get in my output window: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe.  The app just hangs.